# footer block template won`t update django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

footer block won`t update ..

This is my footer block in the [django-planet: search of footer](https://github.com/matagus/django-planet/search?q=%7B%25+block+footer+%25%7D%7B%25+endblock+%25%7D&ref=cmdform) templates/base.html

> {% block footer %}{% endblock %}

And this is from templates/planet/base.html

> {% block footer %}
>       {{ block.super }}
>       {% blocktrans %}A [django-planet](http://github.com/matagus/django-planet) powered site{% endblocktrans %}
>
> {% endblock %}

When i change something in the above code its doesnt change after refreshing in the local server

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/templates/#template-inheritance) in your child template using [`extends`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/templates/builtins/#std%3atemplatetag-extends) template tag e.g.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}

{% block footer %}
{{ block.super }} {% blocktrans %}A django-planet powered site{% endblocktrans %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

See this is my project structure..

i changed footer to "A readtamil powered site" but in the runserver it`s not updating .. Why ?

for the reference i attached the image in my site take look [templatebasehtml](http://readtamil.com/templatebasehtml.png) and [template planet base html](http://readtamil.com/planetbasehtml.png)

After changing still shows only "A django powerd site" instead of "A readtamil powerd site" .. WHy?